# List in a text file all urls contained in specific html A tag

Tags: python, html, bash, web-scraping, terminal

I'm trying to list all urls from a webpage but only the ones in a specific html A tag.

for example the urls targeted are the ones in html A tags containing "Info science":

```
bunch of html before

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url1&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="doc" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> science</a>

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url2&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="image" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> bio</a>

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url3&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="doc" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> science</a>

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url4&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="image" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> bio</a>

bunch of html after
```

the end result should be:
list_links.txt

```
https://url1&amp;rl=h1
https://url3&amp;rl=h1
```

I tried in a linux terminal:
`lynx -dump https://website_to_scrape | awk '/https:/{print $2}' > list_links.txt`

but I of course I get all urls on the web page. Which is already a step forward.

I also tried
`grep -r science source.html > list_links.txt`
but I get a list of all html strong tags containing the word science.

My knowledge is limited but it would be great to have a solution in bash script or something I could do from the terminal.
I'm open for other solutions of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`xmllint`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) tool with specific *xpath* pattern:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//a[contains(., 'Info science')]/@href" source.html
```

---

```
 href="https://url1&amp;rl=h1"
 href="https://url3&amp;rl=h1"
```

---

To extract raw urls pipe to `sed` substitution:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//a[contains(., 'Info science')]/@href" source.html \
| sed 's/href=\|"//g'
```

---

```
https://url1&amp;rl=h1
https://url3&amp;rl=h1
```

Comment: This XPath looks very familiar ^^

Comment: is there a way to feed the url of the web page to that command line?

Comment: You need to use `curl` before. So `curl -s <URL> | xmllint ... | sed` ^^

Comment: thank you. It's showing the list of xmllint options instead of the result. I must be missing something. ```curl -s https://url | xmllint --html --xpath "//a[contains(., 'Info Science')]/@href" | sed 's/href=\|"//g' > list_links.txt```

Comment: Better use `xidel` ;) Only one call/one line

Comment: @JD76, add `-` at the end of `xmllint` command (means read from stdin): `curl -s https://url | xmllint --html --xpath "//a[contains(., 'Info Science')]/@href" - | sed 's/href=\|"//g' > list_links.txt`

Comment: thank you but xidel is also a bit out of my depth. I'm trying to make it work but it seems I'm missing a few things. I get line 113 command not found.

Comment: thank you. I've added the ```-``` at the end but I get ```HTML parser error: Document is empty``` ```XPath is empty```

Comment: @JD76,  can you share the URL address you're trying to download from?

Comment: it's not live just yet but the url is as follow: ```https://www.mywebsite.com/?p=sciences&id=122-books```

Comment: thanks but i'm still not there yet. I haven't found yet a way to feed an URL to the command line. I keep getting the same error. ```HTML parser error: Documment is empty - Xpath is empty```

Comment: @JD76, are you sure that the web-page `https://www.mywebsite.com/?p=sciences&id=122-books` even contains any hyperlink with `'Info science'` ?

Comment: yes I am sure. Part of the things I trippled checked.

Answer (score 3):

### Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) in command line in a shell (don't use `awk` nor regex):

```
xidel -e '//a[contains(., "Info science")]/@href' -s <FILE or URL>
```

### Required output

```
https://url1&rl=h1
https://url3&rl=h1
```

Works for Linux, MacOs, Windows, BSD...

Check https://github.com/benibela/xidel

Answer (score 1):

In Python...

Given the HTML data as a string then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = """
<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url1&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="doc" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> science</a>

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url2&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="image" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> bio</a>

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url3&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="doc" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> science</a>

<a rel="external nofollow" title="something" href="https://url4&amp;rl=h1" target="_blank">
<strong class="image" style="color:#000000">Info</strong> bio</a>
"""
soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a.getText().strip() == 'Info science':
        print(a['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
https://url1&rl=h1
https://url3&rl=h1
```

Comment: thank you. how would I go about feeding the script the url of the web page or worst case scenario the source.html file?

Comment: If the HTML is coming from a web page then you should look at the *requests* and/or *selenium* modules. If it's a file then just open the file and pass its contents to BeautifulSoup

Comment: No need the whole Python and BS4 for this simple task

Comment: @GillesQuénot The only reason for posting a possible Python solution is because OP tagged python - presumably because she wanted that option.

Comment: thank you. it is a great solution. And yes I've added the tag Python. Unfortunately it's a bit out of my depth. On the good side, I am now aware that there are such things that I can learn with python. So I will definitely later read more about  BeautifulSoup, how it works and how to use.